# Grails: How to access i18n from controller or service?

Tags: grails

I have made this controller, which should be used to send emails. I need to access `i18n` in order to send localized emails.

```
class MailController {

    MessageSource messageSource 

    static transactional = false

    public void sendEmail() {
        String name = "some name..."
        String subject = message(code:"somemessagekey", args:[name])
        // do some fancy stuff here...
    }
}
```

There is the `i18n` file then (located in `i18n` folder):

```
file name: messages.properties
content: somemessagekey = Blabla {0} - blablabla
```

After I run this, it throws (in an integration test):

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: messageSource
>   for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.support.MockApplicationContext

I am out of ideas how to handle that localization in controller (I also tried it in a service, but that is even more complicated).

Comment: don't you need to call g.message() ?

Comment: Why should I do so? I have found no info about "g".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are using grails 1.3.7, you need to declare message source as :

```
def messageSource
```

This way it will be injected into your controller. I think in 2.0 you can do it the way you posted, but it even so, I think it is worth a try to declare it as stated above.

Comment: Yes, that helped, thanks. Working code is: `def messageSource 
 public void sendEmail() {
   String subject =  message(code:"somemessagekey", args:[name]) ...`

Answer (score 15):

I know there is an answer, but here's my take at it. I have made a service (inspired by others)

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j
import org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequest
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource
import org.springframework.context.MessageSourceResolvable

@Slf4j
@CompileStatic
class I18nService {
    
    MessageSource messageSource

    /**
     *
     * @param msgKey
     * @param defaultMessage default message to use if none is defined in the message source
     * @param objs objects for use in the message
     * @return
     */
    String message(String msgKey, String defaultMessage = null, List objs = null) {
        String resolvedMessage = messageSource.getMessage(msgKey, objs?.toArray(), defaultMessage, localeForRequest)

        if (resolvedMessage == null || resolvedMessage == defaultMessage) {
            log.warn("No i18n messages specified for msgKey: ${msgKey}")
            resolvedMessage = defaultMessage
        }

        return resolvedMessage
    }

    /**
     * Method to look like g.message
     * @param args
     * @return
     */
    String message(Map args) {
        if(args.message instanceof MessageSourceResolvable) {
            return messageSource.getMessage(args.message as MessageSourceResolvable, localeForRequest)
        }
        return message(args.code as String, args.default as String, args.attrs as List<String>)
    }
    
    private static Locale getLocaleForRequest() {
        GrailsWebRequest.lookup()?.locale ?: Locale.default
    }

}
```

Now, in a service just inject i18nService and you're good to go! This also makes unit testing of other service a breeze as you can mock the i18nService

As a bonus, the service will attempt to find the current locale for the current webrequest, taken that the service runs in a webrequest context.

Comment: Updated for Grails 4.x and forward.

Answer (score 7):

In Grails 2.2.3 it should work:

```
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource
...
def MessageSource messageSource
...
String subject = messageSource.getMessage("somemessagekey", [name], null)
...
```

Reference link and more possibilities here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html

Comment: shouldn't def MessageSource messageSource be MessageSource messageSource or def messageSource? declaring def and the class is redundant.

Answer (score 7):

Answer above did not help me.
I am using Grails 3.0.1 and solution below was useful for me

```
import org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder as LCH
import grails.util.Holders;

class MyService{

def messageSource = Holders.getGrailsApplication().getParentContext();

public String MyMethod()
{
    String message = messageSource.getMessage("code",args,LCH.getLocale());
}

}
```

Comment: If you need to call a controller's method from another controller messageSource will be null. (At least for me). So, may it is interesting setting it by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The official way is actually quite easy. [The official documentation](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/i18n.html#readingMessages) states the following:

> It's simple to read messages in a controller since you can invoke tags
>   as methods:
>
> ```
> def show() {
>     def msg = message(code: "my.localized.content", args: ['Juan', 'lunes'])
> }
> ```
>
> The same technique can be used in [tag libraries](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/single.html#taglibs), but if your tag
>   library uses a custom [namespace](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/single.html#namespaces) then you must prefix the call
>   with `g.`:
>
> ```
> def myTag = { attrs, body ->
>     def msg = g.message(code: "my.localized.content", args: ['Juan', 'lunes'])
> }
> ```

Also, please note to not provide args when your translation doesn't use arguments:

```
def msg = message(code: "my.localized.content")
```

Comment: This answer is only valid for controllers. It does not work that way in services.

Answer (score 1):

I am using grails 3.x.Injected `messageSource`

> `org.springframework.context.MessageSource`

and used

```
String getMessage(String code, Object[] args, String defaultMessage, Locale locale);
```

this method.Modify your code to

```
class MailController {

    MessageSource messageSource 

    static transactional = false

    public void sendEmail() {
        String name = "some name..."
        String subject = messageSource.getMessage('somemessagekey', [name], '', null)
        // do some fancy stuff here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried below code and its working using Holders.

```
def messageSource = Holders.getGrailsApplication().getMainContext().getBean("messageSource")

String errorMesssage = messageSource.getMessage('validation.error.catalogue.not.found', null, messageSource.getMessage(
                        'validation.error.catalogue.not.found', null, 'No Content found for the Reserved Instance Plan Catalogue', locale), locale)
```